# finding 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th not NULL values in a row (SQL)

Tags: sql, impala

```
ID |val1 | val2 | val3 | val4| val5| val6

1   NULL   NULL     a     b    NULL  NULL

2   NULL   NULL   NULL    b     c    d
```

For those two records I want to extract 2nd and 3rd not null values. Desired outcome:

```
ID | 1st | 2nd | 3rd

1.    a    b    NULL

2.    b   c     d
```

---

Let me rephrase the problem as this is original format of data I am dealing with. I thought finding Nth not null value would be easier
There are 3 shops. Each shop sells up to 6 products. Each product can be receive a raiting from 1 star to 6 stars.

shop_id | prod_id | rating

1    |  a      |   2

1    |  b      |   6

2    |  a      |   5

2    |  b      |   6

2    |  c      |   1

2    |  d      |   2

3    |  a      |   3

I want to rank each product according to the rating. Desired outcome would be:

shop_id | prod_id | rating | rank

1    |  a      |   2    |  2

1    |  b      |   6    |  1

2    |  a      |   5    |  2

2    |  b      |   6    |  1

2    |  c      |   1    |  4

2    |  d      |   2    |  3

3    |  a      |   3    |  1

I hope this is clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This will require lots of typing...

Comment: Your schema is bad. Instead you should have `id | val | val_id`, then this would be a trivial `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM yourtable WHERE val IS NOT NULL;`. Your current schema is a pivot and, as such, is going to be a nightmare to get these types of results set out of.

Comment: What DBMS do you use? Add the tag.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

Your schema would be better as `id | val_id | val` which, with your data, would look like:

```
+----+--------+------+
| id | val_id | val  |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 |      1 | NULL |
|  1 |      2 | NULL |
|  1 |      3 | a    |
|  1 |      4 | b    |
|  1 |      5 | NULL |
|  1 |      6 | NULL |
|  2 |      1 | NULL |
|  2 |      2 | NULL |
|  2 |      3 | NULL |
|  2 |      4 | b    |
|  2 |      5 | c    |
|  2 |      6 | d    |
+----+--------+------+
```

So that you can answer your question like:

```
SELECT <TOP 5> * FROM yourtable ORDER BY id, val_id <LIMIT 5>
```

Where `<TOP 5>` and `<LIMIT 5>` are interchangeable depending on which RDBMS you are using.

To get your data to look like this better schema you can use a UNION query:

```
SELECT id, 1, val1 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, 2, val2 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 3, val3 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 4, val4 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 5, val5 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 6, val6 FROM yourtable
```

You can pop that into a subquery in place of `yourtable` in the SQL I have above:

```
SELECT <TOP 5> * 
FROM
    (
        SELECT id, 1, val1 FROM yourtable
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT id, 2, val2 FROM yourtable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, 3, val3 FROM yourtable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, 4, val4 FROM yourtable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, 5, val5 FROM yourtable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, 6, val6 FROM yourtable
    ) yourtable 
 ORDER BY id, val_id <LIMIT 5>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am using impala and LIMIT in <> does not work. Let me rephrase my problem little bit

Comment: Just do `ORDER BY id, val_id LIMIT 5` I didn't mean a literal `<>`. Also remove the `<TOP 5>` I was just using those as placeholders since you hadn't specified your RDBMS so it could have been either `TOP` or `LIMIT` depending...

Comment: Please have a look at the start of the thread. I rephrased the problem a little bit and I am not sure that solution with limit will work.